# vscode with sfdx plugin eating too much memory

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I have started using vscode with sfdx plugin to work with my sandbox and noticed that sfdx plugin inside vscode is taking too much memory. Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

Is this normal? or Do i need to change any setting?

Comment: You can open the issue directly here https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode . They will need specific details and have a template about reporting this .Hope that helps .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this is a well known issue with the Salesforce vscode extension  and Salesforce is working to fix this .

You can track down here

https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/968